# Can i run a executable on AMD x64 which is build on intel x64 platform?

Tags: .net, 64-bit, processor

I have a .Net executable build on Intel i7 and that executable I want to run it on 
AMD. Will it be possible ?

Comment: Intel and AMD x64 processors are *very* compatible for user-mode code.  So much so that Microsoft only uses a single jitter for both.  So yes.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://visualstudiohacks.com/articles/visual-studio-net-platform-target-explained/):

> C# and VB.net compilers only generate IL code that is taken to native code by the CLR at runtime using the just-in-time compiler

So the answer is "Yes!".